# Daily application

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an application that allows the user to access some information only once a day else to show the user how longer does he have to wait until it can see again that information. 
Here is my code:

```
    long aux_time = prefs.getLong("AUX",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Log.v(TAG, "aux=" + aux_time);
    Log.v(TAG, "time" + System.currentTimeMillis());

if(System.currentTimeMillis() > aux_time + (10000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    {   

        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Castle.this, Hug.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }        
   if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= aux_time + (10000 * 60 * 60 * 24))     
    {  
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
        editor.putLong("AUX", System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.commit();

        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Castle.this, Hug_Accepted.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I tested the code. And, I believe, it does open after 24h, but it doesn't opens when I first open the Activity because there is a difference of 0.00000000001 ms between those two when I compare them in the second if. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Jave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9703798/165674)

1. Don't check of equality with current time, instead check `if
   (System.currentTimeMillis() > aux_time + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))`.
   Here you check whether the current time is greater than aux_time by
   at least 24 hours.
2. What is the role of 'k' here? It's value is never used.

Comment: Or he could use a `Calendar` or `Time` Object in this case to avoid problems with the special cases when a day has more than/less than 24 hours (daylight savings).

Comment: I was thinking this way. User's access to that restricted activity was stored in k. When k==1 then the user may enter the Activity, if it was 0, not. I was trying to do something like this. K would have remained 0 until the current time = aux time (even if the application closed), when the equality was true, k=1 would have been true too until the opening of the activity.

Comment: Tried out this one. I believe this code for my If is right, but still my application always allow the user to enter the activity, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

well, all you gotta do in your app is have some sort of database or local file for keeping track of daily usage. So for example if you had an database with columns "id", "lastViewed" (time in mills or date as string).

now everytime you run your main activity, in onCreate check in the database if lastViewed was yesterday or earlier, if not then show user appropriate message otherwise let user in and mark in database datea and time.

Comment: Ok, ok. I got ideas, but I can't manage to make a working code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very strange, first of all, you call `finish()` in some of the if-blocks, but not `return;`, meaning you will continue to evaluate the next if-block (in the one where you check if `millis == aux_time` you set `k=1` which means the next block `k==1` will always be run).

Secondly, you are comparing the time in milliseconds `System.currentTimeMillis()==aux_time` will never be true unless called twice the same *millisecond*, but maybe I am misunderstanding your code?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. After the finish() I have an Intent that changes my activity. As for the comparing thing, yes, that was my problem, and I didn't know how to solve it. I will try Dheeraj answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working version of the code.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    long aux_time = prefs.getLong("AUX",0);
    Log.v(TAG, "aux=" + aux_time);
    Log.v(TAG, "time" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    if(aux_time==0)
    {  
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
        editor.putLong("AUX", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Log.v(TAG, "aux2" + aux_time);
        editor.commit();

    //Open restricted activity
    }

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() < aux_time + (10000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    {   


        //Open the "Not Allowed" activity
    }        

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() > aux_time + (10000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    {  
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
        editor.putLong("AUX", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Log.v(TAG, "aux2" + aux_time);
        editor.commit();


        //Open the restricted one
    }
```